# Azure search - how to implement multiple facet search?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

For example, if we have category facet and it returns withe 5 different categories, on clicking of the first category, the other categories will not be available in the response. I want to implement multiple facet search. 
Appreciate your response.

For more info, i am referring the same scenario as below:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7762452-provide-multiselect-facets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facet in the response is limited to the selected and this feature is not supported. I'd suggest to vote for it here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7762452-provide-multiselect-facets

A workaround is to send multiple queries to get facets and filtered results separately.

For example,
1. keep all facets in the UI (or make another query to get all facets) after the first search query; 2. make another search query after another facet is selected provided that the application tracks what facets the user has selected.

Comment: Link is broken. New link: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/7722fcba-0325-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8

Answer (score 0):

if you want to filter results with multiple facets , you can modify your filter as below :

```
$filter = search.in(country, 'USA,Canada,Mexico,Brasil,Chile,Argentina', ',')
```

> The **first parameter** to the **search.in** function is the string field reference (or a range variable over a string collection field in the case where search.in is used inside an any or all expression). The **second parameter** is a string containing the list of values, separated by spaces and/or commas. If you need to use separators other than spaces and commas because your values include those characters, you can specify an optional third parameter to search.in. 
>   This **third parameter** is a string where each character of the string, or subset of this string is treated as a separator when parsing the list of values in the second parameter.

For more information about OData expression syntax for filters and order-by clauses in Azure Search, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#filter-examples).

Comment: In this case, i will not get the all other facets from the filter. This seems to be a limitation in azure search

Answer (score 0):

I've recently run into this limitation and my workaround was to run a separate query for each facet as suggested by @rudin above.

Let's say for example that your application has facets for Colour, Brand and Size. Your primary search query includes all three filters but doesn't return any facets. You then run an additional query ignoring any selected Colours, which will give you all available colour values for the chosen brands and sizes, and you do the same for the brand and size facets.

For the additional queries it's important to set the 'Size' property to 0 so no search results are returned - just the relevant facet.

By doing this and running these queries asynchronously the performance overhead is minimal in my case with 6 facets.